# Merge and quick sort time result anomaly

Tags: javascript, sorting, quicksort, mergesort

I am currently working on my investigation for my Extended Essay. I am testing the comparison between the merge and quick sorting algorithms. I am having this weird anomaly with my results. Every first sort in my second for loop return a much higher time taken than the rest. I have no clue why, could someone maybe explain?

For some reason, JSFiddle will not output anything, though when I run it locally it works fine. So, I'll just post the code here:

```js
function generateRandomArray(l, min, max) {
  var a = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    a.push(Math.ceil(Math.random() * max + min - 1));
  }

  return a;
}

function quickSort(a) {
  var less = [],
    pivotList = [],
    greater = [];

  if (a.length <= 1) return a;

  var pivot = a[0];

  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i] < pivot) less.push(a[i]);
    else if (a[i] > pivot) greater.push(a[i]);
    else pivotList.push(a[i]);
  }

  less = quickSort(less);
  greater = quickSort(greater);

  return less.concat(pivotList, greater);
}

function mergeSort(left, right) {
  if (!left) return right;
  if (!right) return left;

  var result = [],
    leftIndex = 0,
    rightIndex = 0;

  while (leftIndex < left.length & rightIndex < right.length) {
    if (left[leftIndex] <= right[rightIndex]) {
      result.push(left[leftIndex]);
      leftIndex++;
    } else {
      result.push(right[rightIndex]);
      rightIndex++;
    }
  }

  if (leftIndex != left.length) {
    var temp = left.slice(leftIndex, left.length);

    result = result.concat(temp);
  } else if (rightIndex != right.length) {
    var temp = right.slice(rightIndex, right.length);

    result = result.concat(temp);
  }

  return result;
}

function mergeSortSplit(a) {
  if (a.length <= 1) return a;

  var middle = Math.floor(a.length / 2);

  var left = a.slice(0, middle),
    right = a.slice(middle, a.length);

  left = mergeSortSplit(left);
  right = mergeSortSplit(right);

  return mergeSort(left, right);
}

window.onload = function() {
  var timeResults = [
    [[], [], [], [], []],
    [[], [], [], [], []]
  ];

  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (var j = 3; j < 6; j++) {
      var array = generateRandomArray(Math.pow(10, j), 1, 100);

      var mergeSortTime = window.performance.now();
      mergeSortSplit(array);
      timeResults[0][j - 3].push(window.performance.now() - mergeSortTime);

      var quickSortTime = window.performance.now();
      quickSort(array);
      timeResults[1][j - 3].push(window.performance.now() - quickSortTime);
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < timeResults.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "<b>" + (i + 1) + ". </b><br>";

    for (var j = 0; j < timeResults[i].length; j++) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "<b>" + Math.pow(10, j + 3) + ": </b>";

      for (k = 0; k < timeResults[i][j].length; k++) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += timeResults[i][j][k] + "<b> | </b>";
      }

      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "<br><br>";
    }

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "<br><br><br>";
  }

  console.log(timeResults);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>EE Investigation</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="demo"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `return [a, a];` looks suspicious. Do you want two references to the same array, or two different arrays with the same elements?

Comment: Where's the fiddle? How is anybody supposed to know what's wrong?

Comment: `var pivot = a[0];` is not an optimized pivot. Your `quickSort` will perform worst-case when the array is sorted.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts plus the whole point of quicksort is to not allocate additional memory.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I have rewritten the code from https://brilliant.org/wiki/quick-sort/ to work in JS.
Since this is a research essay, I kind of have to use the code from there. But that is not what is creating the problem, since the merge sort also has this anomaly.

Comment: @ggorlen That is just to use two identical arrays. This is to not use array.splice

Comment: @Pointy What do you mean. I litterally wrote that there is no fiddle. There is a code snippet...

Comment: @ggorlen Since he's notify modifying the arrays in place, there's no problem with multiple references to the same array. But then there's no reason to return two arrays, either.

Comment: But as Pointy suggests, quicksort should usually be used for in-place sorting.

Comment: The second iteration run a more optimized code : https://ponyfoo.com/articles/an-introduction-to-speculative-optimization-in-v8

Comment: @Barmar I understand that, but since this is a research essay, I have to use the exact code I am provided.

Comment: @pleup You should post a summary as an answer.

Comment: @LukasKnudsen but in your question you explicitly mentioned JSFiddle??

Comment: Also when you create your array `[a, a]` you have an array with two references to the **exact same array**.  When you sort the first one, that also sorts the second one.

Comment: @Pointy I have fixed this now.